# Problems with joining two tables but with different number of records in each

Tags: php, mysql, join

I hope someone might be able to shed some light onto my problem.

I have two tables that relate to products within a customer order. One table is called order_product and the other is order_option. I need to join these tables in order to match the product with the relevant option. However, not all product have options and that is where my issue lies.

Here are the list of columns from each table which hold relevance in my query:

> order_product table:
>
> - order_product_id
> - order_id
> - name
>
> order_option:
>
> - order_id
> - order_product_id
> - name
> - value

Let's just say I have Product A which has no options, and Product B which has an "Size" option.

My current statement is:

```
SELECT * FROM order_product op 
LEFT JOIN order_option o ON o.order_id = op.order_id 
WHERE op.order_id = 1
```

However, due to the fact that the order ID of 1 is in the order_option table, all it does is attach the "Size" option to both products.

I then tried:

```
SELECT * FROM oc49_order_product op 
LEFT JOIN oc49_order_option o ON o.order_id = op.order_id 
WHERE op.order_id = 1 AND op.order_product_id = o.order_product_id
```

but I then only get the result for Product B, the only one with the Size option.

Essentially, the only unique match here is the order_product_id but because Product A does NOT have an option, that product id does not exist in the order_option table therefore there can be no result. I'm thinking perhaps I'll need some kind of IF ELSE statement but I'm not sure how they work in MySQL. I'm hoping that I don't need 2 queries here also....

Any help appreciated, thank you!

Michael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the condition `op.order_product_id = o.order_product_id` to the `JOIN ON` clause instead of `WHERE` like

```
SELECT op.* FROM oc49_order_product op 
LEFT JOIN oc49_order_option o ON o.order_id = op.order_id 
AND op.order_product_id = o.order_product_id
WHERE op.order_id = 1;
```